# El resultado al registrar un usuario se desborda y cambia por completo?

Tags: array, c, string, lista, estructuras

(soy novato).
mi problema o mi pregunta radica en que al tiempo del registro donde un socio, se le pide su nombre, apellidos he id, eso funciona tal cual el meollo llega al mostrar sus datos (que cabe mencionar que se asigna a ese mismo socio una ahorro de 200 y una varible de prestamo en 0) ahi esta el problema; en el ahorro este, al registrar el primero, sale bien, al segundo en adelante se desborda en varios numeros. llegue a la conclucion que se trata de un problema del lugar de vector, pero nose como solucionarlo. Aparte esto solo sucede al agregar una parte de codigo (nesesario), pero si se lo quito funciona perfectamente. Se diria que ahi esta el problema no?, pero segun mi entendimiento esas dos partes no interactuan directamente o al meno no de forma que lo pueda modificar. ahi esta la parte que si le quito funciona bien.

```
case 7:
                printf("\n\n\t\t**HA SELECCIONADO, REPORTES**\n\n");
                getch();
                int a=0,p=0,s=0,c;
                float total=0,totalp=0;
```

al parecer el erro sucede solo incluso son agregar las variables.

```
struct menu
{  //variblaes del menu de GERENTE
 char IDempleado[50], nombre[50],apellidop[50],apellidom[50],contrasena[50];
 char origiN[50],origiP[50],origiM[50]; //variables que matienen los nombre y apellidos originales
 //variables del menu de EMPLEADOS
 char IDsocio[50],nombreS[50],apellidoPS[50],apellidoMS[50],IDahorro[50], IDpago[50], IDretiro[50],IDprestamo[50],fecha[50];
}x[MAX];

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   system("COLOR F0");

   int menu1,submenu,capturado=0,indice=0,i,encontrado,n=0,datmodifica,modifica,l=0;
   char contra[20],buscar[20],retry='r',usuario[20];
   char *gerent="gerente",*contraG="1212";
   char num[50]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50'};

   int capturadoS=0,indiceS=0,prestamocont=0,pagado=0,ingreso=0,ret=0,prest=0;
   float prestamos[50],ahorro[50];
```

Aqui la parte del registro del socio en cuestion (se recuerda el primer caso funciona bien, a partir del segundo es donde se malogra). aquie es el unico lugar donde se usa ahorro en la parte de registro del socio

```
                            ahorro[indiceS]=ahorro[indiceS]+200;
                            prestamos[indiceS]=0;


                            indiceS++;
                            capturadoS++;
```

y aqui es donde muestro la lista de socios

```
case 2:
                printf("\n\n\t\t    **HA SELECCIONADO, MOSTRAR LISTA DE SOCIOS**\n\n");
                getch();
                if (capturadoS==0)
                           {
                             printf("No se han capturado registros \n");
                             break;
                           }

                for(i=0;i<capturadoS;i++)
                {
                  printf("\nNombre: %s",x[i].nombreS);
                  printf("\n1mer Apellido : %s",x[i].apellidoPS);
                  printf("\n2do apellido: %s",x[i].apellidoMS);
                  printf("\nSe registro en el\nDD/MM/AA\n%s \nSu ahorro es de: $%.0f",x[i].fecha,ahorro[i]);
                  printf("\nPrestamos: $%.0f",prestamos[i]);

                  printf("\nIDsocio: %s",x[i].IDsocio);
                  printf("\n\n\tSu IDpago es: %s",x[i].IDpago);
                  printf("\n\n\tSu IDahorro es: %s",x[i].IDahorro);
                  printf("\n\n\tSu IDretiro es: %s",x[i].IDretiro);
                  printf("\n\n\tSu IDprestamo es: %s",x[i].IDprestamo);

                  printf("\n****************************\n");
                }
                printf("\n\nPulse R o r para repetir: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c",&retry);
                break;
```

yo creo que el problema radica en esas partes. ya lo simplifique.

Comment: olvide decir que este problema sucedia ta bien con prestamo, y sicneremante nose como lo solucione por que hice lo mismo con ahorro, y no funciono.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pasa realmente con ese programa? ¿A que te refieres con desbordar? ¿A desbordamiento de búfer? ¿El programa deja de funcionar? o ¿Está ocurriendo un fallo de segmentación? ... Debes de tratar de simplificar ese código, está muy extenso, ...

Comment: con desbordar me refiero a lo que se muestra al imprimirlo. ejemplo 1ercaso: ahorro: 200- 2do caso ahorro: 494745983928748400000000000000 y asi cucesivamente esa cantidad. al parecer en un testeo mas esto ocurre al incluso solo agregarle las variables.  -MrDave1999

Comment: Al parecer, el arreglo NO esta siendo inicializado en cero  (0) y cuando tratas de acceder un valor, estas trallendo la basura en esa posicion de memeoria. Trata de inicializar el arreglo en ceros (0) cuando lo declaras y immediatamente despues.

Comment: @Luis su respuesta fue exitosa. No se si guste ponerla como la respuesta definitiva a esta pregunta, o yo la responda por usted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, el arreglo NO esta siendo inicializado en cero (0) y cuando tratas de acceder un valor, estas trallendo la basura en esa posicion de memeoria. Trata de inicializar el arreglo en ceros (0) cuando lo declaras y immediatamente despues. – @Luis

@Luis su respuesta fue exitosa. No se si guste ponerla como la respuesta definitiva a esta pregunta, o yo la responda por usted

Comment: Pero si ya la respondiste por el...

Comment: Ya la solucion esta aqui para ayudar a otros....puedes marcar esta como la respuesta y, si gustas, me das un punto en mi comentario. :)